# Variable into Json Object - Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have this code:

```
function my_json_function(my_variable) {
    var json_var = {
        my_variable: [{
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Doe"
        }, {
            "firstName": "Anna",
            "lastName": "Smith"
        }]
    };

    return json_var;
}
```

So, the problem is:

I pass to the function a variable named `my_variable`, and I want to assign it to the name of the json group.

So, I explain what I mean:
For example if `my_variable = "employees"`, the function have to produce the following result:

```
"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}
]
```

I've tried to casting like this: `String(my_variable)`, but it return me the error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

where am I wrong? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the comments inline in the code:

```
function my_json_function(my_variable) {
    var json_var = {
        peoples: [{
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Doe"
        }, {
            "firstName": "Anna",
            "lastName": "Smith"
        }]
    };

    var obj = {}; // Create empty object
    obj[my_variable] = json_var.peoples; // Assign the data  in the new key

    return obj; // return newly created object
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use an assignment with brackets instead:

```
var json_var = {};
json_var[my_variable] = [
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna",    "lastName":"Smith"}
];
```

Inside the object literal it isn't possible to have a dynamic key name based.

Comment: this is not what he wants, he first needs to clone the old data

Comment: @Vorge What do you mean?

Comment: `For example if my_variable = "employees", the function have to produce the following result:`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use bracket notation rather than dot notation.

```
function my_json_function(my_variable) {
    var json_var = {};
    json_var[my_variable] = [{
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe"
    }, {
        "firstName": "Anna",
        "lastName": "Smith"
    }];

    return json_var;
}
```

Note the use of `json_var[my_variable]` with square brackets. This will create a property in the object with whatever variable is passed in.